# Why is getDate() a month off?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to iterate over objects that have a date within a specific time frame. These time frames are days in the past week bounded by `startDate` and `endDate`.

I have a for loop that sets the `startDate` to the beginning of the day, and `endDate` will be the end of the day.

```js
let startDate = new Date(); // startDate: Start bound of average execution time calculation
let endDate = new Date(); // endDate: End bound of average execution time calculation

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          // i is used to decrement the startDate to i days from today

          // set startDate to beginning of the day
          startDate = new Date();
          startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - i);
          startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
          console.log(i + ": " + startDate);

          // set endDate to end of the day
          endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
          endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
          console.log(i + ": " + endDate);
```

However, even though I'm setting the `endDate` to the `startDate`, the console tells me that the `endDate` is one month off. Why is this happening?

The console shows this:

```
0: Sat Aug 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
0: Sat Aug 01 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
1: Fri Jul 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
1: Mon Aug 31 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
2: Thu Jul 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
2: Sun Aug 30 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
3: Wed Jul 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
3: Sat Aug 29 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
4: Tue Jul 28 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
4: Fri Aug 28 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
5: Mon Jul 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
5: Thu Aug 27 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

Comment: Please don't include images of code output. Use text instead.

Comment: Also, your example gives `undefined: Invalid Date`.

Comment: Dates in JavaScript are numbered 0 to 11

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm sorry about that. I updated it so that I showed that I initialized endDate beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Think like arrays, where the first element is 0. The same is true here. The months of the year will be 0 - 11, rather than 1 - 12. The `getMonth()` method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).

Also, keep this in mind: With `setDate()` the expected values are 1-31, but other values are allowed: 0 will result in the last day of the previous month. -1 will result in the day before the last day of the previous month.

Comment: I see, thank you. However, I'm not sure how to use that information to solve this. I'm setting endDate to startDate by using endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()), so are their getter and setter methods relying on two different counting systems? Also, what makes this even more confusing is that the first iteration worked. Why is that?

Comment: My updated answer also discusses how `setDate()` can produce unexpected results.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it has nothing to do with the ECMAScript zero–based month number.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up just fixing it by not referring to `startDate` at all. I'm not sure why I can't call `getDate()` without getting the wrong date, but for now, I'll just set `endDate` by repeating whatever I did to `startDate`.

```js
// set startDate to beginning of the day
startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - i);
startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(i + ": " + startDate);

// set endDate to end of the day
endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - i);
endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 59);
console.log(i + ": " + endDate);
```

Comment: See my updated answer for details on why you can end up with unexpected results with `setDate()` as well.

Comment: *getDate* returns the correct date, the problem is the OP doesn't update the month for *endDate* when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it happens is because you are setting the date but not the month, so when the loop crosses a month boundary, the start goes to the previous month but end stays in the current month.

When run on 1 Aug, in the first iteration both start and end are set to 1 Aug.

In the next iteration, 1 is subtracted from the start so it's 31 July, but then just the date is set for end, so it goes to 31 Aug, and so on…

A reworking of the code:

```js
// Start at random time on 1 Aug
let d = new Date(2020,7,1,15,23,51,3);

for (let start, end, i=0; i<7; i++) {
  start = new Date(d.setHours(0,0,0,0));
  console.log(i + ' : ' + start.toString());
  end = new Date(d.setHours(23,59,59,999));
  console.log(i + ' : ' + end.toString());
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
}
```